# django-tables2 stylesheet not loading

Tags: css, google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-nonrel, django-tables2

I'm using Django-nonrel 1.5 and django-tables2

I'm outputting a table and it renders correctly, however there are no styling applied from the paleblue stylesheet (table has 'paleblue' class). I then added a table class with the `attrs` metadata but it didn't make a difference.

Whether I'm using:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="{% static 'django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

it doesn't work. It does strangely enough return a 200 at this url

```
http://localhost:8000/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css
```

with the response body:

```
Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8000/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css
```

(which does not change after reloads)

Being appenginge, I'm using gaenv and the django-tables2 is thus in this location:

> project_root/gaenv_lib/django_tables2/static/django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css

I've added `django_tables2` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`, and `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` also has `'django.core.context_processors.request',` (by default)

What am I missing to get the correct path to the css in dev env?

Comment: It`s automatically updates the sys.path or you manually did ?

Comment: It seems I need to run collectstatic on the localhost to get my stylesheets allocated and picked up by django-nonrel. Once I know why `STATICFILES_FINDERS` doesn't work I'll answer the post